# Questions about Lipschitz function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f : X \to Y$ be a function. We say f is Lipschitz if there exists a constant C such that d(f(x), f(y)) $\leq$  Cd(x, y).

a) Prove $f(x) = x^{2}$ is not Lipschitz on R.

b) Prove that the function $f : R^{2} \to R$, where f(x) is the distance from x to the unit circle, is Lipschitz.

c) If $f : [1, b] \to R$ is a differentiable $f$ whose derivative is continuous. Prove that $f$ is Lipschitz.

Could you tell me if my solutions for a), b) are correct and help me solve c)?

For a), I thought 
For $x_1, x_2$ $\in$ $X$, $|x_2^{2} - x_1^2| \leq C|x_2-x_1|$
which means $|x_2+x_1| \leq C$.
Since this should be true for x1,x2 its impossible since C is a fixed value.

For b), I thought we can draw a triangle by linking a point x, a point y and a center of unit circle. Then each line's length will be |f(x)|, |f(y)| and d(x,y).

Hence, $d(x,y) > |f(x)| - |f(y)| = d(f(x), f(y))$
So there exists C(=1) such that d(f(x), f(y)) $\leq$  Cd(x, y)

I have a no idea about c).

Answer (score 2):

Hint for (c): $f'$ is continuous on a compact set and therefore bounded, and for $y>x$ we have $d(f(x),f(y)) = \int_x^y f'(t) dt$.